# How to re-render only deselected and selected items with MobX?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mobx, mobx-react

I have [**the following app**](http://jsbin.com/bamapewele/edit?js,output) that allows me to click on todos in a list and only have one todo selected at a time:

```
class State {
  @observable todos = [
    { id: '1', description: 'Do this' },
    { id: '2', description: 'Do that' },
    { id: '3', description: 'Do this third thing' }
  ]
}

const state = new State();

const TodoView = observer(({ todo, isSelected, onClick }) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}> 
    { todo.description } { isSelected && ' (selected)' } 
  </div>
));

@observer
class App extends Component {
  @observable selected = null;
  render () {
    return <div> 
      { state.todos.map((todo) => 
       <TodoView
         key={todo.id}
         todo={todo} 
         isSelected={this.selected === todo} 
         onClick={() => this.selected = todo} />
       )} 
    </div>;
  }
}
```

The entire list of todos is re-rendered when I select a new todo. Is there any way to just re-render the selected and deselected todos, without cluttering the state with additional data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a `selected` observable in the `App` component that every `TodoView` relies on, you can use an observable `map` and give each `TodoView` an own key to observe. Pass this `map` as a prop to the `TodoView` and check if the `map` has the todo's id as a key. [**This way only the selected and deselected todos will be re-rendered**](http://jsbin.com/voqubogodi/edit?js,output):

```
class State {
  @observable todos = [
    { id: '1', description: 'Do this' },
    { id: '2', description: 'Do that' },
    { id: '3', description: 'Do this third thing' }
  ]
}

const state = new State();

const TodoView = observer(({ todo, selectedMap, onClick }) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}> 
    { todo.description } { selectedMap.has(todo.id) && ' (selected)' } 
  </div>
));

@observer
class App extends Component {
  selectedMap = observable.map({});

  onClick = (todo) => {
    this.selectedMap.clear();
    this.selectedMap.set(todo.id, todo);
  };

  render () {
    return <div> 
      { state.todos.map((todo, idx) => 
       <TodoView
         key={todo.id}
         todo={todo} 
         selectedMap={this.selectedMap} 
         onClick={() => this.onClick(todo)} />
       )} 
    </div>;
  }
}
```